# Using Margin and Padding properties

Tags: css, html

I am new to front end development- HTML/CSS. I was playing with CSS properties: "Float" and "Position:Fixed". When I run the code(given below), i got an output where the floated text and text from #static3 div tag were positioning itself in such a way that some text got hidden behind the fixed text. To make the output appear correctly, i applied the margin property for both the float text and #static3 text. For the float text the output got corrected, but for #static3 text, the whole page moves down when i apply margin property. Both are defined under seperate "div" tag(block  element), then why both of them  work differently.
Please help.

HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is a layout example page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Layyouts.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="static1">This position changes</div>
        <div id="static2">
            This is some text thats using float attribute to be placed on right side while other text goes around and i need to make this text long to have a better look when this page is turned into a html page so better i write more
        </div>
        <div id="static3">This is a random text for the static example. There are many different ways you can use our services – to search for and share information, to communicate with other people or to create new content. When you share information with us, for example by creating a Google Account, we can make those services even better – to show you more relevant search results and ads, to help you connect with people or to make sharing with others quicker and easier. As you use our services, we want you to be clear how we’re using information and the ways in which you can protect your privacy.

Our Privacy Policy explains:

What information we collect and why we collect it.
How we use that information.
The choices we offer, including how to access and update information.
We’ve tried to keep it as simple as possible, but if you’re not familiar with terms like cookies, IP addresses, pixel tags and browsers, then read about these key terms first. Your privacy matters to Google so whether you are new to Google or a long-time user, please do take the time to get to know our practices – and if you have any questions consult this page.
        </div>
        <div id="static4">This is a random text for the static example. There are many different ways you can use our services – to search for and share information, to communicate with other people or to create new content. When you share information with us, for example by creating a Google Account, we can make those services even better – to show you more relevant search results and ads, to help you connect with people or to make sharing with others quicker and easier. As you use our services, we want you to be clear how we’re using information and the ways in which you can protect your privacy.

Our Privacy Policy explains:

What information we collect and why we collect it.
How we use that information.
The choices we offer, including how to access and update information.
We’ve tried to keep it as simple as possible, but if you’re not familiar with terms like cookies, IP addresses, pixel tags and browsers, then read about these key terms first. Your privacy matters to Google so whether you are new to Google or a long-time user, please do take the time to get to know our practices – and if you have any questions consult this page.
        </div>
        <div id="static5">This is a random text for the static example. There are many different ways you can use our services – to search for and share information, to communicate with other people or to create new content. When you share information with us, for example by creating a Google Account, we can make those services even better – to show you more relevant search results and ads, to help you connect with people or to make sharing with others quicker and easier. As you use our services, we want you to be clear how we’re using information and the ways in which you can protect your privacy.

Our Privacy Policy explains:

What information we collect and why we collect it.
How we use that information.
The choices we offer, including how to access and update information.
We’ve tried to keep it as simple as possible, but if you’re not familiar with terms like cookies, IP addresses, pixel tags and browsers, then read about these key terms first. Your privacy matters to Google so whether you are new to Google or a long-time user, please do take the time to get to know our practices – and if you have any questions consult this page.
        </div>
        <div id="static6">This is a random text for the static example. There are many different ways you can use our services – to search for and share information, to communicate with other people or to create new content. When you share information with us, for example by creating a Google Account, we can make those services even better – to show you more relevant search results and ads, to help you connect with people or to make sharing with others quicker and easier. As you use our services, we want you to be clear how we’re using information and the ways in which you can protect your privacy.

Our Privacy Policy explains:

What information we collect and why we collect it.
How we use that information.
The choices we offer, including how to access and update information.
We’ve tried to keep it as simple as possible, but if you’re not familiar with terms like cookies, IP addresses, pixel tags and browsers, then read about these key terms first. Your privacy matters to Google so whether you are new to Google or a long-time user, please do take the time to get to know our practices – and if you have any questions consult this page.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code :

```
#static1{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: 0px;
}

#static2{
   width: 200px;
   float: right;
   border-top: 2px black solid;
   border-bottom: 2px black solid;
   margin: 50px 4px 4px 4px;
   padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px; 
}

#static3{
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6F8DE/)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @belthazorNv Thankyou, its already been answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** I think I understand what you meant to ask. The thing with the whole page moving down when you add margin to `static3` is due to these things:

- The `static1` has `position:fixed` but not actual position properties ( `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom`), so it positions itself relatively to the following element which is `static2`
- The `static2` element has a `float:right` property, therefore it is positioned relatively to `static3` (its `margin-top` is calculated relatively to the top position of `static3` and not the top of the `body`)

That way, all the elements in your page are positioned relatively to the position on the `static3` div. When you add margin to that element, the other two recalculate their positions relatively to the new coordinates.

**Old Answer**

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if the goal is for the "article" to not be overlayed by its "title" (`#static1`), just add a `top:0` property to `#static1`:

CSS

```
#static1{
    top:0; // ADDED THIS LINE
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    ...
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6F8DE/3/)

The thing is you have to specify a position when you use `position: fixed`, or else the browser will understand that your element must not move from its original position, but will not necessarily render it in the desired position. Here, the browser understands that the `static1` has to be rendered "at the top of `static3` and then fixed there no matter what"

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, now i am able to understand what happened in the output. So from my understanding, i have to specify a position i.e. top/right/left/bottom whenever the position:fixed property is used.

Comment: You are not forced to, the results will just be different. I made a fiddle to illustrate that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jp9xt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of internal workings of CSS parser, but I can tell you that changing *margin-top* to *padding-top* in your **#static3** section does solve the problem.

I've been there and that's how I solved my problem. Try for yourself.